# The application could not be installed: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES

Tags: android, certificate, apk, android-manifest

```
11:45   Gradle build finished in 38 s 984 ms

11:45   Failed to commit install session 80875563 with command cmd package install-commit 80875563.

 Error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES: Package /data/app/vmdl80875563.tmp/0_app-release has no certificates at entry AndroidManifest.xml

11:45   Session 'app': Installation did not succeed.
                The application could not be installed: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES
                Retry
```

I have tried:

1. Invalidating and restarting.
2. Build Bundle/APK
3. Install APK and run apk in Phone after delete app
4. Version Code, Version Name increase

(Generate apk is working) but (`run 'app'` and install using apk is not working)

Tools → generate signed bundle or apk → choose exisitng → next → check V1 debug, relase → finish

This method generated apk but my phone can't install when use this apk

```
-----build.gradle (project) -----
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
        }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }

    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}



-----build.gradle(app)-----

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias '-'
            keyPassword '-'
            storeFile file('Insert KeystorePath')
            storePassword '-'
            v2SigningEnabled false
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "root packagepath"
        minSdkVersion MIN_SDK_VERSION as int
        targetSdkVersion TARGET_SDK_VERSION
        versionCode VERSION_CODE as int
        versionName VERSION_NAME
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled false
        }
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
            debuggable true
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    dexOptions {
        jumboMode true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }
}


-----gradle.properties-----
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m

VERSION_NAME=2.1.9
VERSION_CODE=33

COMPILE_SDK_VERSION=28
TARGET_SDK_VERSION=28
MIN_SDK_VERSION=21
```

Answer (score 0):

My case is our app has package name `com.a.b`, and depend on a library with name `com.a.c`, but same time has demo app `com.a.c.d` from library.
After remove `com.a.c.d` my app install successfully.

This problem also happen when I use a unreliable usb connection cable